# Trun off third party SDK after process exit/close/kill

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process

I've written a C# application which uses System.Diagnostics.Process class to create a process, using

```
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

The process is invoked by a ServiceInvoker. 
The service calls a third party DLL in cource of its duration.

After waiting for a certain time I kill the process using,

```
process.Kill();
```

Even after killing the process if the DLL is executing it wont stop.

**Kill** does not invoke the OnExit event of process.
So how can I stop the DLL execution in this case.

Any help in this matter is appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to kill the process and its children?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Kill a process, and all of its children, grandchildren, etc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pid">Process ID.</param>
    private static void KillProcessAndChildren(int pid)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
          ("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid);
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            KillProcessAndChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
        }
        try
        {
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
            proc.Kill();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // Process already exited.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Turn your machine off and and again [sic].... then run it. Maybe something else has the DLL open too.

Comment: I don't think so .But still I will try this too.